# Database Migrations on an existing large database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database-migration

Is it feasible to start using a  Migration framework such as [RikMigrations](http://www.codethinked.com/migrations-in-c-using-rikmigrations) or [Tarantino](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-tarantino-project-automated-database-migrations-and-more/) on an existing large legacy database? The schema is still being tweaked all the time, so I was hoping to use migrations to manage these tweaks.

The database is SQL Server 2008 and has 600 tables 300 views and 2000 storedprocs? I'm just a bit concerned that the initial migration to get where we are now, would be impractical/slow/error prone?

Comment: I would of thought that depends on the resources you have available. Though if its being tweaked all the time that will make things harder.

Comment: +1 on looking for an answer to this :)

Comment: what you mean by feasible? If any chance, I would not like to touch such a db. But if the system needs to be extended - what else would you do with its data than migrating?

Comment: @bendemes the migrations would be to implement these tweaks. Why would that make it harder?

Comment: @user49 Iv edited my question, does this make it clearer?

Comment: @Dan forget my comment clearly didn't clock on to what you were asking. The edits make it much clearer. I haven't used either of those frameworks so can't help with the actual question but you might be interested to note we use a tool called RedGate SQL Compare to help generate generate update scripts for our DBs.

Answer (score 1):

Why not version control your database and keep track of changes that way?  Red Gate has some brilliant products for managing changes to databases:

- [SQL Source Control](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/): version controls your database (almost any VCS: Mercurial, Git, SVN, etc) and enables easier database development within a team as you can all have your own dedicated databases to work on.   You can also version control your static data using this tool.
- [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/): Used to compare 2 databases (say, version control vs your TEST or PRODUCTION database), export scripts and synchronise databases
- [SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/): Used to compare static reference data required by your applications (like enum values, country lists, etc)

Our team has been much more productive and database changes done with confidence by using these tools.  I wrote a couple of posts about it here: http://davidduffett.net/post/4663483715/database-continuous-integration-and-deployment-with-red